# How do I set the MySQL error level?

Tags: mysql

Given the following table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Test (
 id int(10) unsigned NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 value int(10) unsigned NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

If I insert a value with only the `id` field set:

```sql
INSERT INTO Test (id) VALUES (1);
```

On my development server, I get a warning:

> Warning: #1366 Incorrect integer value: '' for column 'value' at row 1

On my production server, I get an error:

> ERROR 1364 (HY000): Field 'value' doesn't have a default value

What should I configure on my development server to make it behave like my production server?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-mode.html

You can set this for your current session, or in your mysql config

*my.cnf (Unix operating systems) or my.ini (Windows)*

```
sql-mode="modes"
```

On your production server use the following query to determine the current mode:

```
SELECT @@GLOBAL.sql_mode;
SELECT @@SESSION.sql_mode;
```

On your development server you can set it for the current session with

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode = 'modes';
SET SESSION sql_mode = 'modes';
```

Comment: Thanks, the difference was `STRICT_TRANS_TABLES` that was set on my production server but not on my development server!